# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/response/Response

Tags: java, selenium, jackson, rest-assured, jira-rest-api

POJO class for login to Jira localhost.

```html
package com.rest.requestpojo;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class LoginApi {
 
 @SerializedName("username")
 @Expose
 private String username;
 @SerializedName("password")
 @Expose
 private String password;

 public String getUsername() {
 return username;
 }

 public void setUsername(String username) {
 this.username = username;
 }

 public String getPassword() {
 return password;
 }

 public void setPassword(String password) {
 this.password = password;
 }


}
```

service classs to get the response from JIRA post call for login. I am just using main method to check the response.

```html
package com.rest.services;


import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.rest.requestpojo.LoginApi;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

public class Service 
{
 public Response jiraLoginAuth(String username, String password)
 {
  LoginApi login = new LoginApi();
  login.setUsername(username);
  login.setPassword(password);
  
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(login);
  
  RequestSpecification requestSpecification = RestAssured.given();
  requestSpecification.contentType("application/json");
  requestSpecification.body(jsonObject);
  Response response =requestSpecification.post(ServiceURL.jiraLoginUrl);
  
  System.out.println(response);
  
  return response;
  
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Service service = new Service();
  service.jiraLoginAuth("chinmaya","ck2016d");
 }

}
```

Service url to post.

```html
package com.rest.services;

public class ServiceURL {
 
 public final static String jiraLoginUrl ="http://localhost:8080/rest/auth/1/session";
 

}
```

Below is the POM.XML page where all the dependecies are available.

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.restAPIFramework</groupId>
 <artifactId>restAPIFramework</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
   <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.7</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.7</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20180130</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>


</project>
```

Below is the error i am getting during run time. Is there any dependencies or jars missing in POM which causing the issue? Please help me with this i am new to restassured.

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/response/Response
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
 at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.restassured.response.Response
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the scope of rest-assured in your pom file because according to your current configuration that dependency is only available during the test phase.

Try changing it to

```
<scope>compile</scope>
```

Comment: oh silly mistake. Error is gone now. thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Changing my restassured dependency version from 3.0.0 to 3.0.7 solved the problem for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```